# What is decltype of a function in parenthesis?

Tags: c++11, decltype

This code

```
#include<functional>

int foo(char);

int main()
{
    std::function<decltype((foo))> f;
}
```

gives the error:

```
aggregate ‘std::function<int (&)(char)> f’ has incomplete type
and cannot be defined
```

in gcc-4.7.2. I thought it would compile.

I know that I could drop the additional parenthesis to make it work, but I am trying to understand what is happening.

I do not understand why decltype adds a reference. I would think that a function name in parenthesis is a prvalue and thus that decltype deduces the type without adding a reference.

Comment: Also, function has no value per se and its name cannot be converted to an rvalue, so is certainly not a prvalue.

Comment: The expression `foo` is an `lvalue` of type `function of (char) returning int`.  `decltype((expr))` converts an `lvalue` of type `T` to `lvalue-reference to T`, hence the output type `int (&)(char)` or `lvalue-reference to function of (char) returning int`.

Comment: Ohh, this answers my question. I though that foo was an prvalue, because you cannot assign to it. But, yeah, it has a name, you can take its address. So it is of course an lvalue. Thanks.